# hide header and ion-slide from login page globally

Tags: html, typescript

I REALLY NEED YOUR HELP. I am working on ionic2. I applied header and ion-slide globally by writing coding in app.ts as shown in code. But the issue is header and ion-slide is displayed in Login Page(i.e. Userloginpage.html) also, so i trying to hide this using *ngIf  as shown in app.html and the value(i.e. hideLogin) of *ngIf is set in app.ts in condition like if it is login page then 'hideLogin' is false so that ion-slide and header will not display but  It is not working.

Thank you!

Any help is highly appreciated.

here is app.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { WalkthroughPage } from '../pages/walkthrough/walkthrough';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { UserloginPage } from '../pages/userlogin/userlogin';
import { NetworkconnectionPage } from '../pages/networkconnection/networkconnection';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

import { CustomerlistPage } from '../pages/customerlist/customerlist';
import { ProductPage } from '../pages/product/product';
import { CustomerPage } from '../pages/customer/customer';
import { ProfilePage } from '../pages/profile/profile';
import { WalletPage } from '../pages/wallet/wallet';
import { MydayPage } from '../pages/myday/myday';
import { FaqPage } from '../pages/faq/faq';
import { TargetPage } from '../pages/target/target';
import { KnowledgebasePage } from '../pages/knowledgebase/knowledgebase';
import { SupportPage } from '../pages/support/support';
import { OrderlistPage } from '../pages/orderlist/orderlist';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

import { App } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
//import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp {

  rootPage:any = UserloginPage; 
  platform:any;    

  constructor(public app: App,  public storage: Storage,  platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private alertCtrl: AlertController, public toastCtrl: ToastController, private network: Network, public geolocation: Geolocation) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      if (splashScreen) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          splashScreen.hide();
        }, 100);
      }
    });


   if(UserloginPage){
     this.hideLogin = false;          \\not working properly
   }

  }    

  customerList(){
    this.app.getRootNav().push(CustomerlistPage);
  }

  gotoHome(){
    this.app.getRootNav().push(HomePage);
  }

  productList(){
    console.log("Product List");
    this.app.getRootNav().push(ProductPage);
  }

  orderList(){
    this.app.getRootNav().push(OrderlistPage);
  }   

  signOut(){}
}
```

here is app.html

```
<ion-header *ngIf="hideLogin" style="height:55px; background:#63813D" > <!--NOT WORKING--> 

    <div style="float:left; margin-top:14px; font-size:26px; padding-left:20px; color:#ffffff;">
      <!-- <span><ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon></span>&nbsp;&nbsp; -->
      <img src="assets/images/app_tray.png" style="width:20px; height:15px; margin-bottom:5px;"> &nbsp;
      <img src="assets/images/mixbag_logo.png" style="width:100px; height:25px; " (click)="gotoHome()">
    </div>

    <div style="float:right; margin-right:15px; margin-bottom:49px; margin-top:10px;" (click) = "signOut()">
      <div style="float:right; font-size:25px; color:#fff; margin-top:2px;"><b><img src="assets/images/sign_out.png" style="width:30px; height:30px;"></b></div>
    </div>

    <div style="float:right; margin-right:15px; margin-bottom:49px; margin-top:7px;" (click) = "profile()">
      <div style="float:left; margin-top:5px;"><img src="assets/images/profileuser.jpg" style="width:30px; height:30px; "></div>
    </div>

</ion-header>    

<div *ngIf="hideLogin" overflow-scroll="false" style="margin-top:48px; background:#fff;"  >  <!--NOT WORKING-->
  <div style="background:#fff; padding-bottom:3px; padding-top:10px;">
  <div>
    <p class="pslider">
      <ion-slides autoplay="" speed="50000">
        <ion-slide>

          <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td style="width:25%; border-right: 1px solid #A1B588;">
                <div (click)="customerList()"  style="padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; margin-bottom:-10px;" >
                  <b><img src="assets/images/customer_list.png" style="width:50px; height:50px;" />
                  <p style="margin-top:-1px; font-size:12px; color:#64823A;">Customer List</p></b>
                </div>
              </td>

              <td style="width:25%; border-right: 1px solid #A1B588;">
                <div (click)="customerform()" style="padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; margin-bottom:-10px;" >
                  <b><img src="assets/images/add_customer.png" style="width:50px; height:50px;" />
                  <p style="margin-top:-1px; font-size:12px; color:#64823A;">Add Customer</p></b>
                </div> 
              </td>

              <td style="width:25%; border-right: 1px solid #A1B588;">
                <div (click)="productList()" style="padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; margin-bottom:-10px; " >
                  <b><img src="assets/images/product_list.png" style="width:50px; height:50px;" />
                  <p style="margin-top:-1px; font-size:12px; color:#64823A;">Product List</p></b>
                </div> 
              </td>

              <td style="width:25%; border-right: 1px solid #A1B588;">
                <div (click)="orderList()" style="padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; margin-bottom:-10px;" >
                  <b><img src="assets/images/order_list.png" style="width:50px; height:50px;" />
                  <p style="margin-top:-1px; font-size:12px; color:#64823A;">Order List</p></b>
                </div> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>  

          </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>
    </p>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>    

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```